# USB Full Speed driver with MCU in DIP package

Tags: usb-device, high-frequency

I desire to apply a USB driver with a MCU that has a DIP package.
The device should communicate in Full Speed (12 Mbps).

To your experience, is that possible?
Taking into consideration the physical phenomenons of a high frequency communication.

I should clarify that the MCU's GPIO pins would be connected (not directly) to the `D+` and `D-` pins of the USB port (through a resistor as the USB protocol requires etc.)

---

**Edit** (01 July, 09:14 UTC):

I'm looking to implement something like this:
[image: USB Driver Schematic]
The implementation should be possible with any MCU, it doesn't have to be ATTiny2313.
I thought of adding a Parallel-in Serial-out (PISO) shift register in order to lower the load on the MCU.

Comment: What is the application? Are you looking to communicate? single direction or both directions ... turn on 1 thing? I say this because USB is a serial packet based protocol with address decoding required. With the details available I would use a module from http://www.ftdichip.com/ . Post a link to a schematic or use the CircuitLab link to draw it. (someone will post the picture from your link for you)

Comment: @Spoon: The app is to be able to communicate with the PC via USB by an MCU. It doesn't matter which MCU. I prefer build one instead of buying because I'm interested in the making of a circuit that has this ability. This is mainly for learning purposes.

Comment: As an academic exercise it is possible but hard even with the right tools. To me this is a case of others have done it and I can learn from them. I might be able to improve on what they have done (unlikely in my case). But the intersting stuff is doing the never been done before things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to run the 12 MHz signals of full-speed USB through DIP-style leads. If your MCU has a full-speed USB interface built-in, this should work fine.

However, if you try to run the USB signalling on the GPIO pins manually, then the MCU will likely need a clock frequency of 100 MHz or more to keep up. For comparison, the Atmel TinyAVR CPUs run lo-speed USB (1.5 Mbit signalling rate) on 12 MHz CPUs by "bit banging," so the USB protocol is possible to emulate with an 8x cycle-to-frequency ratio.

Comment: Could I lower the frequency by adding a buffer that lightens the load on the MCU?

Comment: No. The MCU needs to run full speed to decode the NRZ coding of the USB bus line. You can lower the frequency substantially by simply using a MCU that has USB Full-speed functionality built-in.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean use a PIC based uC for USB, then there are a few you could use - the [PIC18F4550](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en010300) (and other members of the family) has a full speed USB peripheral and comes in a DIP package.
There are also many other Microchip DIP based PIC uCs with USB peripherals (PIC24, [PIC32 MX2 family](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en556043)) and probably some from Atmel also.

If you mean implement USB in a uC without the peripheral (i.e. in software) then I don't know of anything full speed, but I believe there is a low speed library available for AVRs ([V-USB](http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html)).

Comment: I'm looking to implement this manually, that's what makes this circuit so interesting :)

Comment: I see - can you elaborate on "manually" a little please? Do you want to do something like using V-USB with an AVR? Or do you want to implement the hardware from scratch (e.g. build your own differential driver from discrete transistors/gates) or the firmware? (e.g. write something like V-USB) Or both?

Comment: I want to implement this by firmware. I don't want to use an already made solution like V-USB. Using discrete transistors/gates is optional if it lowers the load on the MCU (The solution should be applicable with almost any MCU available that has GPIO pins).